# npm not installing ExpressJS but installs other packs

Tags: node.js, express, npm

**however npm works fine when installing other packages like react or nodemon, but `npm install express` returns the error below:**

```
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ENODATA: Cache input stream was empty
npm WARN registry Using stale data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! errno EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/express: Integrity verification failed for sha512-IlDTZ/IQdocau79XvXdhI1aadp4XE5TKSPeXqNVHSvWHJJaKN78uBdK+aE+G728z3ZxJBUPLFZgSnBLzwXr5fQ== (/home/thisissahand/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/22/50/d367f21076871abbbf57bd776123569a769e171394ca48f797a8d5474af58724968a37bf2e05d2be684f86ef6f33dd9c490543cb1598129c12f3c17af97d)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/thisissahand/.npm/_logs/2020-06-22T12_01_05_922Z-debug.log
```

**By the way, the project name isn't express or anything similar and my OS is ubuntu 18.04**

Thanks

Comment: what is the version of your node? if you try something like this (node --version) in the console what do you get?

Comment: I use the latest stable version of both node and npm. (node v12.18.1  &&  npm v6.14.5). I also removed and then re-installed node and npm correctly from scratch. and as I said it just gives error when trying to install express. not the other modules. thanks